# Strange MySQL "read-only" error

Tags: mysql, database, debian

I'm experiencing a strange MySQL error, seemingly related to the database's `read-only` flag. A Web application that uses MySQL is running on Debian 7.9. It was running well for weeks, if not more, while, suddenly, attempts to access the application-powered website started producing the following error message on a blank webpage:

> Error: 500 - SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1290 The MySQL server is
>   running with the --read-only option so it cannot execute this
>   statement

The following are the steps that I performed as part of my investigation:

- found and read read relevant info on the Internet (some pointed to MySQL's `read-only` flag);
- based on the above, tried to find the `read-only` flag in MySQL config. file (`my.cnf`) - couldn't find it there, but read that the default value for the flag is OFF anyway;
- verified the filesystem to make sure there is plenty of disk space (`df -h`):

  `Filesystem                           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
  udev                                  10M     0   10M   0% /dev
  tmpfs                                3.2G  1.4M  3.2G   1% /run
  /dev/disk/by-uuid/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  113G   14G   94G  13% /
  tmpfs                                5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
  tmpfs                                7.3G   72K  7.3G   1% /run/shm`
- ran `mysqlcheck --all-databases`: all tables are OK;
- verified that there is plenty of RAM available on the server (`free`):

               `total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
  Mem:      32898332    2090268   30808064          0     425436     970348
  -/+ buffers/cache:     694484   32203848
  Swap:      5105660          0    5105660`
- finally, I have decided to take a "snapshot" of MySQL-related processes (`ps ax | grep mysql`) during the problem's existence and after a temporary fix (DB restart), hoping that it could give people additional context for ideas; here are the corresponding results:

  **Problem:**

  `20307 ?        S      0:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe
  20635 ?        Sl     0:37 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock --port=3306
  20636 ?        S      0:00 logger -t mysqld -p daemon.error
  36427 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep mysql`

  **No problem:**

  `36948 pts/0    S      0:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe
  37275 pts/0    Sl     0:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock --port=3306
  37276 pts/0    S      0:00 logger -t mysqld -p daemon.error
  38313 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep mysql`

**UPDATE:**

I just experienced the issue again and decided to check whether the global read-only flag is set to OFF or not, assuming the latter. My assumption has confirmed:

```
mysql> SELECT @@global.read_only;
+--------------------+
| @@global.read_only |
+--------------------+
|                  1 |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I guess, despite the default OFF value, since it is being overwritten by some process in the system, I will have to set the read-only flag to OFF explicitly and permanently via MySQL configuration file. Will report on results later in an answer.

Comment: Can you confirm that restarting the database solved the problem? Has it come back again since restarting?

Comment: @Eborbob: Yes, I can confirm that the problem eventually comes back after restarting MySQL, hence my reference to restart as "temporary fix".

Comment: Next time the problem occurs try logging into MySQL and running `SET GLOBAL read_only = OFF;` and see if that gets it working again.

Comment: @Eborbob: Ironically, so far it works with no errors :-). However, I will definitely use your recommendation next time the problem occurs. I appreciate your attention and valuable advice (+1). Is setting the read-only flag via `SET GLOBAL` persistent between MySQL server and Linux restarts?

Comment: No, the startup setting of the flag is in your my.cnf file, the syntax above is to change the current setting without restarting. It seems that either 1) something is connecting to your db and changing the settings or 2) MySQL is going into read-only mode of its own accord. If the later I'd expect something in the logs.

Comment: @Eborbob: Thank you for your recent comment (+1). Please see UPDATE.

Comment: It will happen when you are using cluster environment, and your system is pointing to secondary node instead of common url to recover from rollover

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar I was not using cluster environment at the time, so it is not applicable to this case. However, I appreciate you letting me know about this aspect (+1).

Answer (score 26):

If you're in AWS Aurora, [you might be accessing the replica instance which is read-only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46665588/aws-aurora-the-mysql-server-is-running-with-the-read-only-option-so-it-cannot) so you need to use the DB Cluster endpoint instead.

Comment: It wasn't AWS Aurora (and it was a while ago), but thank you for the tip.

Comment: I had this issue and it was indeed the read-only endpoint for the RDS cluster that was being used for the hostname. Changing to the Writer endpoint resolved the issue for me.

Comment: I am using cluster endpoint and still getting the same error.

Answer (score 18):

As I see it there are two broad reasons for why your database is being set to read only:

### 1) MySQL is setting itself read only

I'm not sure what might cause MySQL to go read only, perhaps disk issues or corruption of database? In any case I'd expect something to appear in the logs, so check the MySQL (and system) logs.

### 2) A client is setting the database read only

Clients connecting to MySQL can set the database read only using the command:

```
SET GLOBAL read_only = ON;
```

however to do this the user is required to have `SUPER` privileges. This permission shouldn't be needed for websites, applications, etc that are using MySQL - keep it only for an admin account that you use for administering the database.

Lock down the permissions that each user has so they only have permission to do the things that they need on the databases / tables that are applicable. If you're using some out-of-the-box applications they should come with instructions detailing what permissions are required (e.g. `SELECT, INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE`).

Comment: Just saw your answer. Thank you for your advice (+1). I will double check your points. However, it seems that my fix solves the problem.

Comment: @ Aleksandr , could you please let me how to fix the error

Answer (score 4):

Based on my question's comments (special thanks to @Eborbob) and my update, I have figured that some process in the system resets the `read-only` flag to `ON (1)`, which seem to trigger the issue and results in the website becoming inaccessible. In order to fix the problem as well as make this fix *persistent* across software and server restarts, I decided to update MySQL configuration file `my.cnf` and restart the DB server.

After making the relevant update (in my case, addition) to the configuration file

```
read_only=0
```

let's verify that the flag is indeed set to `OFF (0)`:

```
# mysql
mysql> SELECT @@global.read_only;
+--------------------+
| @@global.read_only |
+--------------------+
|                  0 |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Finally, let's restart MySQL server (for some reason, a *dynamic reloading* of MySQL configuration (`/etc/init.d/mysql reload`) didn't work, so I had to **restart** the database server explicitly:

```
service mysql stop
service mysql start
```

Voila! Now access to the website is restored. Will update my answer, if any changes will occur.

Comment: **UPDATE:** It seems that I was too fast in declaring victory over this problem - it has resurfaced today and it is really frustrating. I will try to investigate a little more, but I have a feeling that it is just simpler to reinstall the whole application suite (even though, it is a pretty involved process). Having said that, without knowing root cause of this problem and how to fix it, what are the chances that the problem will not reoccur after the clean install and I will stuck in the same situation again?

Answer (score 3):

set global read_only = off; 
make read only mode off later it will work sure.

Answer (score 3):

the server might be set to recovery mode
find the innodb_force_recovery in my.cnf and uncomment it and restart the server then run the upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

Not related to the issue, but related to the error 'mysql read-only'.

Make sure you are not trying to write something to a **slave** instance of mysql.

Answer (score 1):

I just experienced the same error and fixed it by connecting to the hostname of the mysql server as opposed to the IP address. I'm not sure why this fixed it but it did. Just FYI

Comment: Not sure whether your fix was applicable to my environment, as I think I have already been using a hostname not IP address. Anyway, thank you for the info.

Answer (score 0):

As Eborbob say it's probably a client,

Did you check your backup tool ?

Do you use some SQL proxy like proxySQL or maxscale ?
For exemple Mascale can enforce readonly by monitoring : https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MXS-1859

Replication Manager can also change READ ONLY flag

Answer (score 0):

The below error:-
The MySQL server is running with the --read-only option so it cannot execute this statement

It occurs when a user not having the write permission for the sql db tries to insert/update some data into the db.

It is quite a valid security error, as it is stating that you currently are having just --read-only rights and hence cannot execute a query that has anything to do with writing.

To resolve this error:-
Get the write access from the DBA.

e.g.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database.table TO 'user'@'localhost';
```

The above query will grant all privileges to the user with username 'user'.

Answer (score 0):

executing below statement worked for me
**mysql> SET GLOBAL read_only = OFF;**

[image: mysql cmd]

Answer (score 0):

We are running the **Aurora cluster** and strangely the issue was because we updated the parameter group with `long_query_time = 0` for the read-only cluster. As we reverted `long_query_time = 1` it's fixed.

Answer (score -5):

This worked for me and you can try it.

Make a backup of your .sql file ( change your query )

Find all `Engine=InnoDB`
and replace them with `Engine=MyISAM`

and try executing again.

Comment: This is a major change with very large consequences that it is probably not wise to follow.