# AWS Aurora: The MySQL server is running with the --read-only option so it cannot execute this statement

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I am getting this error when executing a `GRANT` statement on my Aurora DB instance in AWS:

> The MySQL server is running with the --read-only option so it cannot execute this statement

My user is not read-only though, so why is this happening?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

It turned out to be a silly mistake, but posting it anyway in case anyone else has the problem:

I was accessing the replica instance by mistake - I had copied the endpoint for the replica, and it is read-only apparently. So if you have this problem, verify that you are connecting to the Primary Instance or best of all the DB Cluster endpoint.

**Edit:** According to @Justin's answer we definitely should use DB Cluster:

> You need to connect to the cluster, rather than an instance. This is because instances seem to take a turn to be the readers and writers.

Comment: I read this answer and thought, _well that's not **my** problem_... turns out it was -- for my situation I'm using an AWS hosted Aurora DB and have been using the read VIP for weeks. Suddenly today it stopped allowing me to do any writes... I'm not sure what switch flipped, but flip it did indeed.

Comment: Same thing happened to me, after 2 weeks the endpoints did switch

Comment: Interesting. . . this just happened to me too.  I have no idea why the writer/replica endpoints switched.

Comment: Wasn't so obvious for an Elastic Beanstalk user like me.  To find your Cluster endpoint:  1. Go to https://console.aws.amazon.com/rds/, 2. Click on Clusters on the left menu, 3. Click on your Cluster name, 4. In the first section titled Details you'll see a line item 'Cluster Endpoint'.  Use that

Comment: This just happened to me today. Endpoints switched. Thankfully caught early.

Comment: I am connecting to DB cluster end point that I created by adding both the instance read and write. But still when I am updating something with cluster end point is saying "The MySQL server is running with the --read-only option so it cannot execute this statement"

Comment: This can also be caused by not connecting using the `--ssl`option

Answer (score 11):

You need to connect to the **cluster**, rather than an **instance**. This is because instances seem to take a turn to be the readers and writers.

Comment: I have created cluster endpoint and connected with that. But whenever I am using update query it saying The MySQL server is running with the --read-only option so it cannot execute this statement.

Comment: I also have tried this.  My app points to cluster endpoint and not an instance and yet the app cannot write. Get running in read-only.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was receiving this error after performing a Blue/Green failover in a Test environment.  I was trying to access the Blue database, in order to confirm the process for reverting back to Blue database should that be required later.

Accessing Blue via the cluster address yielded this error, as did attempting to use the direct links to the Blue "reader" and "writer" instances.  In the end, I performed a failover of the Blue "reader" and "writer" instances, after which the cluster address was in a working state again.

tl;dr

Try a failover of the "writer".